# Change color of submit button

Tags: css, angular, angular2-forms

I am working on angular material 2. What I am trying is to validate the form and submit it if all required fields are filled. I have shown just one field in plunker for brevity. This is the current behaviour:https://plnkr.co/edit/78K2nQi4x7CjvNbLYfUC?p=preview

form.html

```
<form class="example-form" #f="ngForm">

    <md-input-container class="example-full-width">
      <input mdInput placeholder="First name" name="firstname" ngModel required>
    </md-input-container>

 <button md-raised-button [disabled]="f.invalid" color="primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Submit button on validation takes some primary color as mentioned in button element. But I would want it to be a different color like green on validation and not the primary color. I tried removing the color attribute and gave it a green color as you can see in the https://plnkr.co/edit/QwEIcOEHKlsCo8kdyeAh?p=preview; but it shows the color even before validating the form.

How can I achieve this? 
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess I just made it work.

Tried it with `[ng-class]`.

Gave my button `[ngClass]="{'my-class': !disabled}`;i.e. checked whether it had disabled true/false. Then added `my-class` with styles required for button.

Working plunker:https://plnkr.co/edit/78K2nQi4x7CjvNbLYfUC?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Another simple variant:

```
<button md-raised-button [disabled]="f.invalid" [style.color]="'white'" [style.background-color]="f.invalid ? 'gray' : 'green'">Submit</button>
```